# Save random values from multi-dimensional NumPy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, random

I have an 149x5 NumPy array. I need to save some (30%) of values selected randomly from whole array. Additionally selected values will be deleted from data.

What I have so far:

```
# Load dataset
data = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')

# Select randomly 30%(45) of rows from dataset
random_rows = data.sample(45)

# Object for values to be saved
values = []

# Iterate over rows and select a value randomly.
for index, row in data.iterrows():

   # Random between 1 - 5
   rand_selector = randint(0, 4)

   # Somehow save deleted value and its position in data object
   value = ??                                                 <-------

   values.append(value)

   # Delete random value
   del row[rand_selector]
```

To add further, the data from `value` will later be compared to values imputed in its place by other methods(data imputation), therefore I need the position of the deleted value in original dataset.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me. You state, that you want to save 30% of the values, but in the code you are using 30% of the rows.

Comment: Yes because I intended to select 1 value per row then save & delete it. EDIT: you are right I wanted to delete 30% of values but selected rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will, given a 2D numpy matrix `m`, return an array of length `0.3*m.size` containing arrays of length 3 consisting of a random value and its coordinates in m.

```
def pickRand30(data):
    rand = np.random.choice(np.arange(data.size), size = int(data.size*0.3))
    indexes1 = rand//data.shape[1]
    indexes2 = rand%data.shape[1]
    return np.array((data[indexes1, indexes2], indexes1, indexes2)).T
```

You can delete the entries by using its coordinates, however you may want to have a look into [masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) instead of deleting single entries out of a matrix.

Comment: It selects random positions of values on both columns and rows nicely, but return drops the "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'". I'm trying to work around it

Comment: Ok. It works, you have to convert pd Dataframe into numpy array and then pass it to function - just use iris = iris.values